# Delay only one channel of audio stream in mp4 file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

**How can I apply a delay to only 1 audio channel of an mp4 containing a stereo audio stream?**

---

I have a video `test.mp4` with 2 streams:

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8042 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn (default)
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
```

As you can see the AAC track is stereo. I need to apply a **2-second** delay to just the **right** channel in the audio stream (stream 1).

Here is a script that successfully does this for *both* audio streams ([detailed description here](https://superuser.com/a/983153/892036)):

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -itsoffset 2 -i "test.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy "test_delay.mp4"
```

Basically it's using the `-map` option to grab input id `0`'s `v` video stream  (`-i "test.mp4"` is the first, undelayed input with id `0`), along with input id `1`'s `a` audio stream (`-itsoffset 2 -i "test.mp4"` is the second, 2-sec-delayed input with id `1`) to compose the final output.

I think I should be trying to use [`-map_channel`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) instead, but am confused how to incorporate it with the `-itsoffset` option as well.

The following results in a video with no audio streams:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -itsoffset 2 -i "test.mp4" -map 0:v -map_channel 1.1.0:0.0 -map_channel 1.1.1:0.1 -c:v copy "test_delay.mp4"
```

And the following (including `-map 1:a` this time) results in R ch being delayed successfully, but with no L ch at all (mono audio stream):

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -itsoffset 2 -i "test.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -map_channel 1.1.0:0.0 -map_channel 1.1.1:0.1 -c:v copy "test_delay.mp4"
```

Any tips?

---

This command is to be run by an automated and unmonitored system so I'm really trying to keep it limited to just 1 command execution, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`adelay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-adelay) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -i "test.mp4" \
  -filter_complex[1:a]adelay=0|2000[out] \
  -map 0:v -c:v copy "test_delay.mp4"
```

`adelay` takes a sequence of delays in milliseconds, separated by `|`, and stereo channel layout is `LEFT|RIGHT` so set the 2nd delay to be 2000 ms.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Fixed up your example to work as follows: `ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a]adelay=0|2000[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:v -c:v copy -shortest "test_delay.mp4"`.

Comment: I didn't mention this in my original question but maybe you happen to know off the top of your head: what if I need to shift the audio forward instead of delay it? With `-itsoffset` I was just inputting negative values but adelay doesn't seem to accept negative values.

Comment: You can use `-itsoffset` along with filtering if keeping the negative-timestamp samples is important. If you are throwing away the negative-time samples, just start the audio file at your desired starting time using `-ss` *input* option

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doubling down on the filters: `"[0:a]adelay=2000|0,atrim=start=2:duration=99,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out]"`... 1) `[0:a]adelay=2000|0` Delay the LEFT channel, 2) `atrim=start=2:duration=99` Trim the first 2 sec of both audio channels, 3) `asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out]"` Close the gap caused by the trimming... this will ultimately put the LEFT ch back to where it started while the RIGHT ch begins 2 sec sooner.

Comment: For the record: In the `atrim` filter options, `duration=99` is set to 99 because I know for a fact that 99 seconds will be longer than any of the videos that will be processed, which works because elsewhere in my ffmpeg cmd I call the `-shortest` flag which will cut the extraneous audio stream as soon as the video ends.

Answer (score 0):

@kesh's answer is correct but if a single audio channel must be moved earlier in time instead of delayed, see this command which uses filters to offset the right audio stream channel by 2 seconds in `test.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a]adelay=2000|0,atrim=start=2:duration=99,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:v -c:v copy -shortest "test_delay.mp4
```

Note that

- `test.mp4` is known to be shorter than 99 seconds in duration
- `adelay=2000|0` is delaying the LEFT channel by 2000 millis in order to offset what will happen in the following filters; ultimately the left channel will be returned to its original position